# Save capture image with custom size in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

I have created one sample application.For capture image using camera.It is working fine.After capture iam saving image in sdcard . My image saving with 160x120 size i want increase this size. How can i save with custom size.my code is,

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 35, byteStream);

File fStorageDirectory = new File(
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), SDCARD_FOLDER_NAME);

System.out.println("path of----"+fStorageDirectory);

if (!fStorageDirectory.exists())
        fStorageDirectory.mkdirs();

OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/"+ SDCARD_FOLDER_NAME + "/" + IMAGE_NAME); 
outStream.write(byteStream.toByteArray());
outStream.close();
```

please guide me to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this inside OnActivityResult

```
BitmapFactory.Options bounds = new BitmapFactory.Options();
bounds.inSampleSize = 4;
Bitmap myImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(SD_CARD_TEMP_DIR,bounds);
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
myImage.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);
bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();
```

Comment: you can chage bounds value to - bounds.inSampleSize = 1 for actul size image